# Yesterday, my Date.now() overflowed and I can't find any relevant results on Google

Tags: javascript, overflow, epoch

```
1423781658625
```

This number is the overflow. Converted to a date, this is:

```
Thu Feb 12 2015 22:54:18 GMT
```

Has anybody else encountered this issue yesterday?

Comment: What do you mean it overflowed or it is the overflow?

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a value greater than that, so it's not overflowing by itself. Using `Date.now() | 0` to force 32-bit operations does overflow, but that should've started about 23 days ago.

Comment: Javascript numbers are 64-bit floating point, with 53 bits of mantissa. So the maximum integer has 16 digits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here...  and answer the question that was asked.

**Q: Has anybody else encountered this issue yesterday?**

And by *this issue*, you are referring to some kind of "overflow" issue with Javascript `Date.now()`.

I didn't encounter this issue. Nor would I expect to.

Javascript `Date` object supports values 100,000,000 days after 1/1/1970. And the `now()` method returns the value of object as the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970.

There's 86,400 seconds in a day, times 1,000, gets milliseconds in a day, times 100,000,000 gives a maximum value of 8,640,000,000,000,000.

The maximum safe integer value in Javascript is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is equivalent to `Math.pow(2, 53) - 1`, a decimal value of 9,007,199,254,740,991.

The value returned by `Date.now()` isn't going to exceed `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, and even it did exceed that value, it wouldn't "overflow", it would just lose precision.

So, I'm going to go out on a limb, and answer your question you asked:

**A: No. No one else encountered an overflow issue with Javascript `Date.now()` yesterday.**

But I'll also follow that up with a suggestion that it's not `Date.now()` causing an overflow. If there's some type of integer overflow happening in your Javascript code, it's not an issue with `Date.now()`, but with something else you are doing. We could take guesses, but without additional information about what your code is actually doing (like the *actual code*), we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a result of an upper limit on the setTimer function. Thanks for all your replies!